# Connect 20 monitors to one PC

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, multipoint-server-2011

I am trying to achieve this using Windows Multipoint Server & USB to VGA/HDMI External Adapters. But this technology only supports up to 14 monitors per PC. (OS limitation AFAIK). These monitors must act as extended displays. Is there a way to remove this limitation? Or an overall better way to do this?

Comment: nvidia quadroplex comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

Windows MultiPoint Server 2011 Premium - 20 stations limit, Standard - 10.

Any Server OS with RemoteFX support - Windows 2012/2008 R2/SBS 2011(75 user limit)/2012(25 user limit). `mstsc` RDP 8 support client.

[Unable to connect to Windows 7 SP1 client on a SBS 2011 Standard or SBS 2011 Essentials domain after it has been updated with RDP 8 update](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/11/03/unable-to-connect-to-windows-7-sp1-client-on-a-sbs-2011-standard-or-sbs-2011-essentials-domain-after-it-has-been-updated-with-rdp-8-update.aspx)